# Redis failed to connect: connection refused from Nginx

Tags: nginx, redis, lua, openresty

I'm struggling with this issue more than a week, and still cannot pull it off.

I'm trying to provision our environment using Ansible, and I want to provision a staging server, with the same environment as production, I have setup the Redis server, and it's running listening on 6379 I have Nginx up and running and it's serving requests, but when it's got to the part of Lua to connect to Redis, it throw on me connection refused error.

Here is Nginx debug log: [Link](https://gist.github.com/Iliyass/63ed001a0cf8e23b63339981aebb9c75)

Redis Listening on 6379

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN | grep 6379
redis-ser  1978         redis    4u  IPv6 138447828      0t0  TCP *:6379 (LISTEN)
redis-ser  1978         redis    5u  IPv4 138447829      0t0  TCP *:6379 (LISTEN)
```

Connecting to Redis through Python

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct  8 2019, 14:14:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import redis
redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db='0')
r.set("Test", 'value')
True
r.get("Test")
'value'
```

Lua Code:

```
local red = redis:new()
red:set_timeout(500)
local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
if not ok then
     ngx.say("Redis failed to connect: ", err)
     return
end
```

Nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name xxx.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/xxxx_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/xxxx_error.log debug;

    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header Host   $host;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $http_cf_connecting_ip;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $http_cf_connecting_ip;
    proxy_set_header X-URI  $uri;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;

    location / {
        rewrite_by_lua_file '/var/www/xxxx/nginx/add_header_web.lua';
        proxy_pass http://xxxxx/;
    }
}
```

Environment

```
Redis 3.2.0
Nginx: openresty/1.7.7.2
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local/openresty/nginx --with-debug --with-cc-opt='-I/opt/ngx_openresty-1.7.7.2/build/luajit-root/usr/local/openresty/luajit/include/luajit-2.1 -DNGX_LUA_USE_ASSERT -DNGX_LUA_ABORT_AT_PANIC -O2 -O2' --add-module=../ngx_devel_kit-0.2.19 --add-module=../echo-nginx-module-0.57 --add-module=../xss-nginx-module-0.04 --add-module=../ngx_coolkit-0.2rc2 --add-module=../set-misc-nginx-module-0.28 --add-module=../form-input-nginx-module-0.10 --add-module=../encrypted-session-nginx-module-0.03 --add-module=../srcache-nginx-module-0.28 --add-module=../ngx_lua-0.9.14 --add-module=../ngx_lua_upstream-0.02 --add-module=../headers-more-nginx-module-0.25 --add-module=../array-var-nginx-module-0.03 --add-module=../memc-nginx-module-0.15 --add-module=../redis2-nginx-module-0.11 --add-module=../redis-nginx-module-0.3.7 --add-module=../rds-json-nginx-module-0.13 --add-module=../rds-csv-nginx-module-0.05 --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib -L/opt/ngx_openresty-1.7.7.2/build/luajit-root/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib' --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --with-http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module --add-module=/opt/nginxmodules/nginx-upload-progress-module --add-module=/opt/nginxmodules/nginx-push-stream-module
```

**Update:**

Well, I just updated my openresty to latest version and things went back to work

Comment: Change your error handling: Instead of `ngx.say`, which outputs to the user, just call `error` to 1) terminate the request then and there and 2) log the error in the error.log file. Or just wrap your call of `red:connect` in `assert()`

Comment: Вevil in detail, I use Redis in tens OpenResty projects and it works. Can you provide a complete environment to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue but figured it out after a bit of help from a [Chinese thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openresty/_3myWBraILA) from a google group. Essentially we have to add options table with the pool name when connecting. I don't know why, but it worked for me.

Here is my code:

```
local options_table = {}
options_table["pool"] = "docker_server"
local ok, err = red:connect("10.211.55.8", 6379, options_table)
```